# MYSQL server shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm trying to run MYSQL (XAMPP) and get the following

```
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-12-10 01:14:22 1260 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 3060372467
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-12-10 01:14:22 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-12-10 01:14:23 4572 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-12-10 01:14:23 4572 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 3060629849
2015-12-10 01:15:45 1260  InnoDB: Operating system error number 1117 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2015-12-10 01:15:45 4572 [ERROR] InnoDB: File C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1: 'Windows aio' returned OS error 1217. Cannot continue operation
```

That's painful, because I have several SQL databases and I can't even back them up; phpmyadmin doesn't work as well. Please, help!

Comment: try removing `ibdata1` (move to some another place) and restart .

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your task manager and killing mysqld by ending the process and then try to restart.

Found a few answers here:

`http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/788dbe5e7413/xampp-mysql-wont-start-error-1217.html`

Also, your phpmyadmin won't work if your database isn't working.